# Sails-mongo. Find in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, sails.js

I'm using sails.js and sails-mongo adapter. Suppose I have a model:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

        shema: true
    ,   attributes: {
                description: {
                    type: 'TEXT'
                ,   max: 200
            }

            ,   tags: {
                    type: 'ARRAY'
            }
    }

  }

};
```

How can I carry out a search in an tags array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Model.find({
    'tags.title': {
        contains: 'query'
      }
})
.done(function (err, response) {
    /**/
});
```

Comment: looking at the code, it runs mongo's $regex which is expensive. It appears that support for mongo's actual array operations doesn't exist

Answer (score -1):

```
db.schools.find( { criteria },
             { atributes: { $elemMatch: { tags: value } } } )
```

there are a great example here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/

with waterline

```
Model.native(function(err, collection) {
    // Execute any query that works with the mongo js driver
    collection.find( { criteria },
                 { atributes: { $elemMatch: { tags: value } } } )
    });
```

Comment: Your answer shows how to carry out this search via the mongo cli.  The question is asking how to implement the search via waterline.js