# Waterline, find array in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have Video model:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    id: 'string',
    tags: 'array'
  },
}
```

I want to find all videos with tags for example "Hello" or "World".
I could easy get all videos like:
Video.find({tags:"Hello"}). I saw examples where searching id: [1,2,3] but not when key(id => tags) is array.

Comment: are you missing a } in your code?

Comment: i updated whole model without functions like (beforeCreate, etc)

Comment: Check out this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110553/sails-mongo-find-in-array

Comment: Probably this helps , too
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22708069/mongodb-find-a-value-inside-the-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Video.find({tags: {"$in" : ["sometag1", "sometag2"]}})
```

Comment: This is when using a mongodb wrapper, here he is using Waterline.

Answer (score 2):

Use the "in"-Statement in combination with "contains"

```
Video.find({tags: { contains: ["some1","some2"]}}).exec(function(err,res){
    console.log(res);
});
```

See: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/queries/query-language.md

Comment: True, this doesn't work. Any idea how to solve this? @harianus did you solve this?

Comment: @Suisse: maybe, but that was in 2015 and I don't use Sails anymore.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this..

```
var filtered = module.exports.filter(function () {
    return this.tags.indexOf("string") != -1
});
```