# Find record in Sails Waterline where an array contains a string

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

Model:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    title:{
      type:  'string',
      required: true,
    },
    content:{
      type:  'string',
      required: true,
    },
    tags: {
      type: 'array'
    }
  }
};
```

Now I want to find all Article, where a given string is in the tags.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24179694/3037960):

```
Article.find({tags: { contains: ["some1"]}}).exec(function(err,result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

But it doesn't find anything.

I am using `sails-disk`. I also tried $in and $or (the Waterline way).

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding that waterline queries on array properties apply the criteria to each element of the array. So if the `tags` property is an array of strings, the expected behaviour would be:

```
Article.find({tags: 'hello'}).exec(function(err, results) {
    // results has all articles with a tag 'hello'
});

Article.find({tags: ['hello', 'hi']}).exec(function(err, results) {
    // results has all articles with a 'hello' or 'hi' tag
});

Article.find({tags: {contains: 'hello'}).exec(function(err, results) {
    // results has all articles with a tag containing substring 'hello'
});
```

I use waterline like this with `sails-mongo`, and it works as expected.

Comment: I tested all of those; none of them works. I am 100% sure it is because of ```sails-disk```

Comment: Is it possible your file data isn't formatted correctly? If you haven't already, maybe try to create a record through waterline and make sure any handwritten records match the formatting.

Comment: No I doublechecked it. It is well formatted. It is created with waterline. Searching in a array in ```sails-disk``` doesn't work. I will test the same with MongoDB and make a comment here. thx.

Comment: Tested: It works with ```sails-mongo```but not in ```sails-disk```

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you do another model named "Tags" and relate "Article" with it. Sails will create the "Join Table" (or another approach) and now you can query for populated values. Take a look at: [docs](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/populate)

Sou you could do something like `Tag.find(criteria).populate('Articles').exec(...)`